# Trying to save images to hard disk give me error: URI formats are not supported

Tags: c#

This is the function im using  and I want to save the images in the links i got from the website on my hard disk.

```
public void GetAllImages()
{

  // Bing Image Result for Cat, First Page
  string url = "http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cat&go=&form=QB&qs=n";


  // For speed of dev, I use a WebClient
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
   string html = client.DownloadString(url);

   // Load the Html into the agility pack
   HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
   doc.LoadHtml(html);

   // Now, using LINQ to get all Images
   /*List<HtmlNode> imageNodes = null;
   imageNodes = (from HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img")
                              where node.Name == "img"
                              && node.Attributes["class"] != null
                              && node.Attributes["class"].Value.StartsWith("sg_t")
                              select node).ToList();*/

   var imageLinks = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
        .Where(n => n.Attributes["class"].Value == "sg_t")
        .Select(n => HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(n.Attributes["src"].Value["amp;url"])
        .ToList();





   foreach (string node in imageLinks)
     {
      y++;
      //Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["src"].Value);
      richTextBox1.Text += node + Environment.NewLine;
      Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(node);
      bmp.Save(@"d:\test\" + y.ToString("D6") + ".jpg");

      }

 }
```

In the bottom in the foreach im using Bitmap but then im getting the error. why ?

Comment: Print out the node string to see what you pass to the Bitmap ctor. I guess it is an URL (from the src attribute of an image). The Bitmap ctor expects a filename to load the file from, but it does not support an URI (as written in the exception). Probably you should download the image from the remote URL using a web request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to download the images first. You can't save images from URIs like that. Get the bytes for the image using WebClient and then create your image using that data.

Something like this:

```
private System.Drawing.Image GetImage(string URI)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData(URI);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data);
        return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
    }
```

Then, I would suggest using System.Drawing.Image.Save to save it out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.save.aspx